# Is it possible to change color of breakpoint confidence intervals?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, piecewise

I am trying to change the color for esthetics in `pwfit.plot_breakpoint_confidence_intervals()` after making multiple linear regression by using piecewise_regression. I tried 'color' option but it gives me any results...

Is it possible?

Comment: please share the code you have so we know what plotting library you're trying to use and how you're performing the fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [`piecewise-regression`](https://piecewise-regression.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html); [the function](https://github.com/chasmani/piecewise-regression/blob/v1.2.0/piecewise_regression/main.py#L899) seems to ignore `kwargs` instead of passing them to matplotlib. You can mostly just copy the existing function and modify it to be a separate function rather than a method and add `kwargs` to the matplotlib call.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_breakpoint_confidence_intervals(fit, **kwargs): #you'll have to pass the Fit object
    """
    Plot the breakpoint confidence intervals as vertical shaded regions.
    Passes kwargs to the matplotlib function, e.g. color="red".
    """

    if not fit.best_muggeo:
        print("Algorithm didn't converge. No breakpoint estimates to plot")
    else:
        estimates = fit.best_muggeo.best_fit.estimates

        for bp_i in range(fit.best_muggeo.n_breakpoints):
            bp_ci = estimates["breakpoint{}".format(
                bp_i + 1)]["confidence_interval"]
            plt.axvspan(bp_ci[0], bp_ci[1], alpha=0.1, **kwargs) #actually pass kwargs to matplotlib here

plot_breakpoint_confidence_intervals(pwfit, c='m')
```

This clearly (from the function docstring) seems like an accidental omission from the author. **edit:** and already seems to have a [bug report](https://github.com/chasmani/piecewise-regression/issues/9).